# Unir con rectas Scatter Plot Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo un diagrama de dispersión como el que se muestra en la figura y quiero unir los puntos con segmentos, pero no todos, sino en grupos de a 5. Es decir, cuatro segmentos que unan los primeros 5 puntos, cuatro segmentos que unan los siguientes 5 puntos y así... son 120 puntos en total, por lo que serían 24 grupos de 5.

[image: Scatter plot]

Este es el código que generó ese gráfico:

```
plt.scatter(np.arange(1,121), mos[0:120])
plt.title('Imagen 1')
plt.ylabel('MOS')
plt.xlabel('Numero de Imagen')
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

¿Cómo agrego los segmentos?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

mos = np.random.rand(120)
y = np.arange(1,121)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(y, mos)

cant = 5
for i in range(0,len(mos),cant):
    lines = []
    for j in range(0,cant-1):
        p = [(y[i+j], mos[i+j]), (y[i+j+1], mos[i+j+1])]
        lines.append(p)

    lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, colors='red', linewidths=1)
    ax.add_collection(lc)


plt.title('Imagen 1')
plt.ylabel('MOS')
plt.xlabel('Numero de Imagen')
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Ten en cuenta que no dispongo del array `mos` así que lo simulo con valores random. Lo que define los segmentos es el siguiente código:

```
cant = 5
for i in range(0,len(mos),cant):
    lines = []
    for j in range(0,cant-1):
        p = [(y[i+j], mos[i+j]), (y[i+j+1], mos[i+j+1])]
        lines.append(p)

    lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, colors='red', linewidths=1)
    ax.add_collection(lc)
```

Es decir, recorremos `mos` en pasos de `cant = 5` y luego armamos los 4 puntos segmentos, estableciendo el punto inicial y el final: `p = [(y[i+j], mos[i+j]), (y[i+j+1], mos[i+j+1])]`. La salida sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: qué hace la línea: fig, ax = plt.subplots() ?

Comment: Retorna una tupla con los valores de `fig` y `axis` (gráfico y ejes), la usamos por que necesitamos justamente acceder a `axis` para graficar la lineas al hacer: `ax.add_collection(lc)`

Answer (score 1):

Debes dibujar las porciones. En lugar de usar `scatter` puedes usar `plot` para obtener el efecto que deseas. Un ejemplo de código sería:

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("bmh") # esto es innecesario

# datos a dibujar
mos = np.random.randn(120)
x = np.arange(120)

# generación del plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(0, len(mos), 5): # iteramos cada 5 valores para 'x' y 'mos'
    ax.plot(x[i:i+5], mos[i:i+5], 'k-o') # 'k-o' indica que queremos que:
                                         #  sea negro -> 'k', 
                                         # se unan con línea continua -> '-'y 
                                         # las uniones sean puntos 'gordos' -> 'o'
                                         # http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot
ax.grid(True)
fig.show()
```

Posible resultado:
[image: Posible ejemplo]